# Redefine variable if new definition is non-empty

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have this:

```
master="master";
integration="integration";

if [ -f '.vcs.json' ]; then
    master=`read_json -f .vcs.json -k git.master`
    integration=`read_json -f .vcs.json -k git.integration`
fi
```

however, I only want to redefine master/integration variables if the results from read_json are non-empty.

I am thinking something like this:

```
master="master";
integration="integration";

if [ -f '.vcs.json' ]; then
    master="${`read_json -f .vcs.json -k git.master`:-master}"
    integration="${`read_json -f .vcs.json -k git.integration`:-integration}"
fi
```

but I am not sure if that syntax is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to act if a string is non-empty, use a parameter default when referencing the variable:

```
master="$(read_json -f .vcs.json -k git.master)"
```

If the subshell commands return no output, the variables will be null.  You can then leverage this with default substitution:

```
do-a-thing "${master-master}" # if 'master' is null, use the default value 'master'
                              # otherwise, use the contents of the variable
```

Comment: that works too, but isn't it `"${master:-master}"` not `"${master-master}"`?

Comment: The difference is that `-` will work if the variable is unset _or null_, while `:-` will only work if the variable is _unset_.

Comment: ah ok thanks, I am not sure what null means in the context of bash tho

Comment: `foo=''` would create an empty (or null) string which is still actually _set_.

Comment: whereas `foo` is null, I guess

Comment: and you prefer `x="$(echo 'foo')"` to `x=\`cat 'foo'\``?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the logic upside down:

```
# Note that the variables 'master' and 'integration' are NOT defined yet
if [ -f '.vcs.json' ]; then
  master="${`read_json -f .vcs.json -k git.master`:-master}"
  integration="${`read_json -f .vcs.json -k git.integration`:-integration}"
fi
# Set default values if empty or missing
: ${master:=master} ${integration:=integration}
# They are now guaranteed to be non-empty
echo $master $integration
```